# Display path with backslash (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, alert, backslash

I try to display a path on an simple javascript alert command :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="fr" xml:lang="fr">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div onClick=myFunction('D:\user\myself\dos')>
    clic here
</div>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE = "JAVASCRIPT">
  function myFunction(p) {
   alert(p);
  }
</SCRIPT>
```

But it does not display the backslash..
I suppose I should replace all "\" by "\" but I don't find a way to do it.
(I tried `p = p.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');` and a lot of other syntaxes but none of those worked.

Do you have any idea of how to deal with that ?

**EDIT :**
The path comes out from a function and I can't edit it directly in "onClick"

Comment: Just hit the backslash key twice when typing the path in the first place. It doesn't many any sense to enter a wrong path and fix it later :-?

Comment: Depending what char is followed by the `\ `  it will have a special meaning. e.g. if the `u` is followed then Unicode sequence is expected. As of that `'D:\user\myself\dos'`  will throw an exception, because `ser` is not a valid Unicode sequence. You always need to escape your `\ `  in the place where you create it, you cant fix that later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backslash '\' itself is used as the escape character.
So add one more backslash before every backslash you are going to display.

In case if you cannot modify url try to add new attribute and access that attribute within `onClick` handler.

Try working snippet below:

```js
function myFunction(elem) {
   alert(elem.getAttribute('data-url'));
  }
```

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="fr" xml:lang="fr">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-url="D:\user\myself\dos" onClick=myFunction(this)>
    clic here
</div>
```

**Update**: Code snippet updated to allow displaying url without modifying string.

Comment: I should have said that I cannot edit the path ! (it comes out of a function with only one backslash and I can't change that)

Comment: \\ is required in string literals, to put a SINGLE \ in a string ... if a function returns with the \ already in the string, your problem is elsewhere

Comment: This is pure genius ! Thanks, I would have never though about that

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call your function with double the backslashes to escape the escape character:

```
myFunction('D:\\user\\myself\\dos')
```

Will this work in your case?